# How to display success data without refreshing IN IE?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

In IE 8 and above it requires page refresh for displaying success data.. in other browser this function work properly But it In IE to see updated data it need page reload

**Code:**

```
$('#ajaxEmpData').on('submit', function (e) {

        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = true;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/candidate/emp',
            data: $('#ajaxEmpData').serialize(),
            error:function(request,status,error) { 
                alert(status); 
                document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "visible";

            },       
            success: function (data) {
                $('body').html(data);   
                }
        });

    });
```

Comment: It looks strange to replace the entire `body` contents with `ajax`. How is it better than reloading the page at all? And if you really want to do so, why don't you use `$('body').load()`?

Comment: $('body').load() with this function also... IE need page reload manualy to show updated data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Event(event).preventDefault();`

through this code is running properly

Comment: Can you provide a little more detail, please?

Comment: $('#ajaxEmpData').on('submit', function (event) {
      new Event(event).preventDefault();        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '/candidate/emp',
            data: $('#ajaxEmpData').serialize(),
            error:function(request,status,error) { 
                alert(status); 
                document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "hidden";
            },
            beforeSend:function(){
                document.getElementById('load').style.visibility = "visible";

            },       
            success: function (data) {
                }});});

Comment: Add it to your answer and provide explanations